# Flutter Web How Can I Read http response's cookies

Tags: flutter, http

I have a Flutter app works in Web and mobile devices. I can get cookies from response.header[] in mobile devices. But i can't access to this cookies in web. How can i read this response's cookies?
Here's how im getting cookies in mobile devices:

```
void setSessionId({required Map<String, String> headers}) {
var box = GetStorage();
box.write("sessionId", headers["set-cookie"]?.split(";").first);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The browser is handling cookies automatically, it doesn't matter how the application is implemented.

Try [cookie](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/Document/cookie.html) property in `document` if for some reason access is needed.